# MySQL AVG() of varchar possible?

Tags: mysql, count, type-conversion, int, varchar

I'm doing an assignment in a database-course at my uni using MySQL. We've made a database of a golf club, where we (among other things) can store players results from different games.

Now I'm writing the report for the assignment, and I'm trying to prove that it's better to use an int rather than a varchar to store the results. If an int is used, disqualified players will get a NULL-value as a result. If a varchar would've been used, they would've got a string: "disqualified".

**The things I'm wondering are:**

1. Does MySQL automatically convert `varchar` to `int` if `avg()` is used (for example) when a calculation is about to happen?
2. If it does, does that slow down the database a lot (compared to if an int would've been used)?
3. Is it possible to do calculations on string-values? E.g. if the result-attribute is a `varchar` containing "52", "68", "72", can the average be calculated?
4. What will happen if I've got the strings listed above plus a result that is "disqualified"? Will it ignore that string like it would've ignored a NULL of an int?

Comment: That is a good think that you are doing a database-course, but you should do it for your self, otherwise you would not learn.

Comment: Well, I am learning a whole lot, and this course is part of my programme. I just need a little bit more information for this report.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your questions can be answered by runing simple tests:

```sql
drop table if exists golf;
create table golf(id int, int_col int, char_col varchar(50));
insert into golf(id, int_col, char_col) values
    (1, 10, '10'),
    (2, 20, '20');

select avg(int_col), avg(char_col) from golf;
```

Result:

```sql
avg(int_col) | avg(char_col)
     15,0000 |            15
```

http://rextester.com/NNAZ9432

As you can see AVG over a VARCHAR column returns the expected result.

Now add a row with `NULL` and `'disqualified'`

```sql
drop table if exists golf;
create table golf(id int, int_col int, char_col varchar(50));
insert into golf(id, int_col, char_col)values
    (1, 10, '10'),
    (2, 20, '20'),
    (2, NULL, 'disqualified');

select avg(int_col), avg(char_col) from golf;
```

Now the results are different:

```sql
avg(int_col) | avg(char_col)
     15,0000 |            10
```

http://rextester.com/RXOQAZ69820

The reoson is: While `NULL` is ignored by AVG, `'disqualified'` is converted to `0` and the result is *(10 + 20 + 0) / 3 = 10*.

To test the performance you can create a big table with dummy data. In MariaDB with the sequence plugin this can be done easily:

```sql
drop table if exists golf;
create table golf(id mediumint primary key, int_col smallint, char_col varchar(50));
insert into golf(id, int_col, char_col)
    select seq id
         , floor(rand(1)*1000) int_col
         , floor(rand(1)*1000) char_col
    from seq_1_to_1000000;
```

AVG over INT:

```sql
select avg(int_col) from golf;
-- query time: 187 msec
```

AVG over VARCHAR:

```sql
select avg(char_col) from golf;
-- query time: 203 msec
```

Last but not least: You should not use string types for numeric values. One more reason is sorting. If you try to sort numbers stored as strings you will get something like *[10, 2, 22, 3]*.

You should also not use one column for different information types. In your case you could define one more column like `status` with values 'finished' or 'disqualified'. Another possible way is to have a flag column `disqualified` with values `0` or `1`.